# AngularJS scope.$watch in directive isn't raised

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I wish to use the $animate library to apply some CSS classes and within my directive I wish to toggle a scope variable value onve the css animation is complete. I wish to show a DIV using the `ng-show` directive, when the condition for this is met (`scope.showPopover === true`) I wish to show the item then it must fade away. I have a custom directive to perform the CSS fade and reset the condition for the ng-show... here's my code

```
<!-- here is the popover, the showPopover and popoverNeeded scope variables are in my controller  -->
<div data-ng-if="popoverNeeded === true" class="nav-popover" data-fade-animation data-ng-show="showPopover">
  I am a popover that will toggle, then fade away....
</div>
```

here are my controller variables...

```
$scope.popoverNeeded = true;
$scope.showPopover = false;
```

here is my custom directive

```
.directive('fadeAnimation', function ($animate) {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            priority: 800,
            link: function (scope, element) {

                console.log(scope.showPopover); // false

                scope.$watch(scope.showPopover, function (newValue, oldValue) {

                    console.log(newValue, oldValue); // undefined undefined

                    if(newValue === true) {
                        $animate.addClass(element, 'fade-animiate').then(function() {
                            element.removeClass('fade-animiate');
                            scope.showPopover = false;
                        });
                    }

                });
            }
        };
    });
```

here is my css...

```
.fade-animiate {
  animation: fade-animiate 2s;
  -webkit-animation: fade-animiate 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  animation-delay: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes fade-animiate {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }

}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-animiate {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }

}
```

Now when the view/page loads the `scope.showPopover` value is output and is correct, we see `false` in the console. The watch values are output as `undefined, undefined`. However when I toggle the `scope.showPopover` value the watch does nothing. I'm not so strong on directives, can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont prefix the values in the `$watch` with `scope` (it also takes a string for the var to watch):

```
scope.$watch("showPopover", function (newValue, oldValue) {
```

Comment: OMG! Of course! Now I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined. But that is great advice!